# Umbraco 12 Surface Controller with custom Model

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, umbraco8, umbraco12

I'm trying to use Surface controller with custom ViewModel. The problem is that when I use '@Html.BeginUmbracoForm' the endpoint is not constructed right. Its point to the same page on what im. I think this is because Model what im using is custom what inherits from 'ContentModel'. I'm out of ideas what I can do.

[custom model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0EDg.png)

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFG7E.png)

[surface controller action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7105.png)

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem but check this, might be helpful. https://our.umbraco.com/forum/developers/razor/41534-using-HtmlBeginUmbracoForm-with-HTTPS#comment-160487